# Escape a valid filename/path

Tags: php, security, file, escaping

So i'm getting into security problems right now, and i want to know what is the perfect approach in making scripts safe. I have somewhere in my code this

```
$AdditionalPath = preg_replace("/^[A-Za-z0-9._-\/\\]/","",$AdditionalPath);
require $AdditionalPath."../xdata/php/website_config/mysql.php";
```

`$AdditionalPath` may be everything, even a malicious code, so i tough to myself that i should let certain characters into that variable, like `A-Z` `a-z` `0-9` `.` `/` `\` . I'm i correct? And also did i made this regex correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: We don't know what constraints you have on `$AdditionalPath`, just make it as restrictive as possible.

Comment: `$AdditionalPath` might be something like `big.bobs.viruses.ru/cgibin`. I really can't think of any possible way this could be safe.

Comment: let's assume that we hafe fopen off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) instead of a regex:

```
$file = realpath( $AdditionalPath . "../xdata/php/website_config/mysql.php");
if( is_readable( $file ))
  require $file;
```

**Update:**

From the documentation of realpath:

> Note: The running script must have executable permissions on all
>   directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE.

Comment: Whatever you do, realpath returns .. the real path. And as the filename is part of the realpath call, it cannot be tempered with.

Comment: but oppening `big.bobs.viruses.ru/cgibin` like `Dan` said it is still possible, if i have `allow_fopen_url` on ... ok, but this is my main problem, stopping inserting malicious code, read here `http://blog.itgossips.com/tech/step-by-step-hacking-website-null-byte-picture-upload/` ... something like this, but there are more examples like that

Comment: No: `realpath('big.bobs.viruses.ru/cgibin' . "../xdata/php/website_config/mysql.php")` will return `false`

Comment: you're right http://codepad.org/2hy4UzLp :) and about the `NULL CHARACTER` and other types of exploits?

Comment: and about `Note: The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE.` , what does it means? for example, i have `mysql.php` CHMOD to 777, is it enough ?

Comment: Nog go! All the `bad things ` are combined with the good thing(../xdata/php/website_config/mysql.php) and that must resolve to a valid executable on the server.

Comment: chmod 777 is to much! use 755

Comment: Yes! It give the owner (you) read/write/executable rights and everybody else read/executable rights (**no writing**)

Comment: I'm beginning to learn every day about security, many months passed since i learned about anti sqli, anti xss (character excaping)... now i'm moving forward with this, thank you!